# Make numbers less than 360 in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

This is my function

```
def price_to_ephe(data):
    converted = []
    for i in data:
        while i >= 360:
            i = i - 360
        converted.append (i)
    return converted
```

it makes every number less than 360. I want to apply it to column in dataframe.

```
2009-01-01, 886.0
2009-01-02, 884.2
2009-01-03, 882.1
2009-01-04, 882.6
2009-01-05, 883.4
2009-01-06, 889.1
2009-01-07, 887.6
2009-01-08, 882.5
2009-01-09, 879.7
2009-01-10, 878.3
2009-01-11, 876.6
2009-01-12, 875.2
```

Expected output:

```
2009-01-01, 166.0
2009-01-02, 164.2
..............
```

...and so on. Numbers can be large and small: 10000 and 20.

Help me please to do it in most efficient way. DataFrame is very large. I need all speed of pandas!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mod.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to get the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo) of your value, which is achieved with [`mod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mod.html) (or `%`):

```
df['modulo'] = df['value'].mod(360)
```

Or:

```
df['modulo'] = df['value'] % 360
```

Output:

```
          date  value  modulo
0   2009-01-01  886.0   166.0
1   2009-01-02  884.2   164.2
2   2009-01-03  882.1   162.1
3   2009-01-04  882.6   162.6
4   2009-01-05  883.4   163.4
5   2009-01-06  889.1   169.1
6   2009-01-07  887.6   167.6
7   2009-01-08  882.5   162.5
8   2009-01-09  879.7   159.7
9   2009-01-10  878.3   158.3
10  2009-01-11  876.6   156.6
11  2009-01-12  875.2   155.2
```

Comment: perfect! Quick and easy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

This method applies a function along the axis to a pandas dataframe. In this case, you can use `df["column_name"].apply(price_to_ephe)`

In case you want to implement it without your own "price_to_ephe" function, you need to use [modulo to reduce](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mod.html) the column by 360.

> df["column_name"].mod(360)

Comment: Jose, thank you, I've tried. But I cannot understand how to do it correctly.

Comment: Seems that your "price_to_ephe" function has the intention but I don't know if it does what you want to do. In this case, apply() is going to apply that function to the whole pandas column. So you need to have in mind your own function is going to be applied into a list of numbers. In this case, the 'for i in data' is probably exploding because numbers are not iterable. You need to redo the function and make it work. So you can just return data - 360.